# Celery Elastic Beanstalk ImportError: cannot import name Celery

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, celery, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to get celery to work on Elastic Beanstalk through Django but not having much luck.

I'm able to use celery on my local machine, but whenever I deploy to Elastic Beanstalk, it doesn't like this line: from celery import Celery.

I looked at a few other questions about this and they said to change the name of my python file of celery.py to something like celeryapp.py but this doesn't change the result.

The error message in full is this:

```
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
  execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
  utility.execute()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 303, in execute
  settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
  self._setup(name)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
  self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
  mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
  __import__(name)
  File "/opt/python/bundle/3/app/MY_PROJECT/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
  from .celery import app as celery_app
  File "/opt/python/bundle/3/app/MY_PROJECT/celery.py", line 5, in <module>
  from celery import Celery
  File "/opt/python/current/app/MY_PROJECT/celery.py", line 5, in <module>
  from celery import Celery
  ImportError: cannot import name Celery
   (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
```

Anyone got any idea why celery can't import Celery? In my requirements.txt I have celery==3.1.18, so I'm assuming the library is installed.

Answer (score 0):

You need django-celery in requirements.txt as well.

Update:
We restart our celery service post deployment as well.

```
commands:
    90_create_post_dir:
        command: "mkdir /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post"
        ignoreErrors: true

files:
    "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_restart_delayed_job.sh":
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: users
        content: |
            #!/usr/bin/env bash
            service celeryd restart
```

You obviously need to setup celery to run as a daemon and that whole bit as well.

Comment: This is the answer. Always be sure to run pip freeze > requirements.txt before deploy from within your virtualenvironment (if you're using one).

Comment: @DeusExMachina25 This isn't correct. I have django-celery in requirements.txt, still getting this error.

Comment: That is part of it. You need celery installed and working as well which is tricky in itself. It is not really what the question was about though.

Comment: Why is `django-celery` needed? I've used Django with Celery and never needed it. Its [page on pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery) says "**THIS PROJECT IS NO LONGER REQUIRED**" (emphasis in the original).

Comment: Oh wow that has changed then! We are not using that project anymore. AWS have their own queue system which make more sense. We redesigned and use AWS Lambda now and don't need a queue.

Comment: Where should I put this script? I have created a new ``99_delayed_job.config`` under the ``.ebextensions`` directory but I get the same error.

Comment: Yes it should be in there. But it has to be under the commands-section, not the container_commands-section. Is celery working if you ssh in to the instance and manually restart it?